# Jupyter javascript kernel installation last comand not working windows 10

Tags: javascript, installation, kernel, jupyter

I am trying to install a javascript kernel into jupyter onto a windows 10 machine that has jupyter installed and NodeJS installed.  I am following this https://github.com/n-riesco/ijavascript under the section Windows (Official Python Distribution).

But when I get to this part:-

```
ijsinstall
# Or run: %appdata%\npm\ijsinstall
```

Nothing works I get:-

```
PS C:\Users\wigl2744> %appdata%\npm\ijsinstall
%appdata%\npm\ijsinstall : The module '%appdata%' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module
%appdata%'.
At line:1 char:1
+ %appdata%\npm\ijsinstall
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (%appdata%\npm\ijsinstall:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule
```

or this

```
PS C:\Users\wigl2744> ijsnotebook
ijsnotebook : The term 'ijsnotebook' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ijsnotebook
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ijsnotebook:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What is the command to invoke the install as when I run

```
jupyter lab
```

And start a new notebook there is no Javascript kernel?  Probably because the last comand won't run!